# AWS Open search service is stuck in processing state since 2 weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

AWS OpenSearch Service is stuck in processing state since 2 weeks and even I tried to curl the endpoint which is giving connection timed out.

How to troubleshoot this domain status which is stuck in processing state?

Cluster configuration details:

No of nodes: 1

- Instance type: m4.large
- Storage type: EBS
- EBS Volume size: 20GB
- Region: N.virginia
- version: 7.7

Comment: Have you find out the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is in region us-east-1, which is notoriously the worst option. AWS is fully aware of the issues in that region but chooses to ignore the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).